# Trigger function on Remove block or add new block in Gutenberg JavaScript

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, hooks, block-editor

I want to perform certain action, when gutenberg block is removed or new gutenberg block is added in post editor.

How do i add lister to this two event in gutenberg javascript ?

Thank you

Comment: what is it that you want to do when this happens? It is necessary to know to answer your question correctly ( it may also be the incorrect approach to what you're trying to do ). What is the problem this solves for you?

Comment: thank you for your reply. consider I want to create log for added and removed blocks.

Comment: so if somehow i can trigger function call on block remove and new block addition, where i can get block details, that would be great.

Comment: you can subscribe to the store which can update you when things change, but you would need to figure out if that meant a block was added or if a block was removed

Comment: That is the issue, I can call componentDidUpdate on something gets changed on editor. But i need something from where i can identify block is removed or added.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't see option to do that